# How to change cursor theme

Tags: mouse, themes, cursor

I've found that changing my cursor theme only really works in applications like Firefox; the cursor is not themed across the OS, but remains as the default cursor.

I have done some searching and I know that there is a bug that forces the user to create an executable file in order to change their cursor theme. Is there really no other way around this? To be honest, I would think this issue should have been fixed a long time ago.

But I digress. I'm looking for a way other than adding/editing a file in order to do something so basic as change my cursor theme. Are there any other options available?

Comment: This does work, but surely there's a better option? Shouldn't switching cursor themes be as easy as switching a window theme?

Comment: Completely agree and if Ubuntu team does not fix this bug I will switch back to pure Gnome 3, because there it works.